# To identify same words in two tabs in a google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

My Query is i want to highlight the duplicates in the two tabs in a sheet. My sheet is attached along with this question. In that "Sheet A" & "Sheet B" have common names in it i want to color it for the duplicates.

Sheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hL64Q7REorVkjJNKAEGPFBdinlIn8VwnE6H7L9fYB2c/edit#gid=0

If it is possible, is there any option to find the duplicates between two google sheets ?
if yes then pls help me to find duplicates in Sheet A in Match 1 sheet and Sheet C in Match 2 Sheet.

Sheet 2 : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xAUmvmaZPvfJwCHD_esrshLccgKM3VmP1CI46mMoRB8/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer that shows how this can be done.  See the tab I added, "Sheet 1-GK", into your sheet.
The formula in C1 looks at the data from Sheet 2 to see whether each name in Sheet 1 column A is found in Sheet 2.
Here is the primary formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(
IF(MATCH(A2:A9,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xAUmvmaZPvfJwCHD_esrshLccgKM3VmP1CI46mMoRB8/edit","'SHEET C'!A$2:A$8"),0),
    "Y",
    "N"),
  "N"))
```

In the sheet, I have wrapped it in an array, {...}, to also add the column header text.

Then a conditional formatting rule is used to highlight the rows that have "Y" in column C.

Note that you can either hide column C, or incorporate its formula logic into the conditional formating rule, to do everything there.

Is this what you were looking for, or did you need something else?
[image]